# copy paste not working in windows 10 office 365 while splitting word document using VBA

Tags: vba, windows, ms-word, copy-paste

The following code split the document by section breaks. however it is working correctly in windows 7 but not in windows 10 office 365, having "run time error 4605 : the command is not available." on windows 10? while I try to paste the copied content using `oNewDoc.Range.Paste`. I came to know it was due to oNewDoc windows not activate or pasting take place without waiting to oNewDoc to be created. because when I press debug and wait for 1 second then run again it executes correctly.

```vb
Private Sub GenerateFiles_Click()

    'Pages Update 1.0 By M.B.A.
   
    Dim oNewDoc As Document
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim CR As Range
    
    Dim firstLine As String
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim DocName As String
    Dim pdfName As String
    
    Dim arrSplit As Variant
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim PS As String

    PS = Application.PathSeparator
    
    'Progress
    pBarCurrent 0

    If pdfCheck.Value = False And docCheck.Value = False Then
        PagesLB = "**Please Select at least one check boxes!"
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
        Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
        Set CR = oDoc.Range
        Letters = oDoc.Range.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)
        Counter = 1
        
    While Counter < Letters + 1
        
        With oDoc.Sections.First.Range
                .MoveEnd wdSection, 0
                .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
                .Copy
                '.Select
            Set oNewDoc = Documents.Add(Visible:=True)
                
                oNewDoc.Range.Paste 'Run-time error '4605': This command is not available
                
        End With
    
        
        firstLine = oNewDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
        For i = 1 To 2
            strLine = oNewDoc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
            If InStr(strLine, ".pdf") > 0 Then
                arrSplit = Split(strLine, ".pdf")
                DocName = arrSplit(0) & ".pdf"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
                
        If i = 3 Then
            
            DocName = Left(firstLine, 45)
            DocName = Replace(DocName, vbCr, "")
            
        End If
                
        DocName = Replace(DocName, Chr(11), "")
        
        pdfName = Counter & " - " & DocName & IIf(i = 3, ".pdf", "")
        DocName = Counter & " - " & IIf(i < 2, Replace(DocName, ".pdf", ""), DocName) & ".docx"
    
        'Debug.Print pdfName; vbNewLine; DocName
        
        If docCheck Then
            oNewDoc.SaveAs FileName:=oDoc.Path & PS & ValidWBName(DocName), AddToRecentFiles:=False
        End If
        
        If pdfCheck Then
            oNewDoc.SaveAs FileName:=oDoc.Path & PS & ValidWBName(pdfName), FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
        End If
        
        oDoc.Sections.First.Range.Cut
        
        
        '== Progress Bar =='
        DoEvents
        PagesLB = " Letter " & Counter & " of " & Letters & vbCr & " " & Int((Counter / (Letters)) * 100) & "% Completed..."
        pBarCurrent Int((Counter / (Letters)) * 100)
        oNewDoc.Close False
        Counter = Counter + 1

    Wend
   
    PagesLB = Letters & " Letters has been Created..."
    oDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Beep
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using the clipboard by using the `FormattedText` property

```
    With oDoc.Sections.First.Range
        .MoveEnd wdSection, 0
        .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        Set oNewDoc = Documents.Add(Visible:=True)
        oNewDoc.Range.FormattedText = .FormattedText
    End With
```

Comment: perfect! worked out very well.